# rollup cant build <style></style> in html tag

Tags: rollup, lit-element

i inject ${this.Classes}  into my html tag in render function.
when i start it with rollup, it works as expected. but when i try to build it with rollup build, it gives error: " html-minifier deleted something major, cannot proceed." and cant build.

```
 render() {
        let dis=this;
        return html`
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/lib/jquery/dist/selectize/selectize.default.css" />

            dis.Style();

            <select id="select"></select>
        `;
    }

    Style() {
        let dis = this;
        return html`
            <style type="text/css">
                 .selectize-input {
                    padding: 0!important;
                    border: none;
                    border-radius: none;
                    background:white!important;
                    box-shadow:unset!important;
                    -webkit-box-shadow:unset!important;
                }

                ${dis.Klasslar}
            </style>
        `;
    }
```

Comment: Are you interpolating correctly `dis.Style()`? (should be `${dis.Style()}`). Also, what is the content of `dis.Klasslar`?

Comment: i mistyped dis.Style(). Yes  it should be ${dis.Style()} . and content of dis.Klasslar is a string returns    .clas{display:none} for example

Comment: slightly off-topic: you should ever need to do the `let dis = this;` assignment - these methods will be called with the correct `this`.

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-minify-html-literals